# Create a virtual directory in wso2

Tags: wso2

I am using wso2 application server v4.0 on Linux.

I have a webapp and I want to have a folder to store files. The folder size can be huge and the application could be redeployed as well, so directory is not inside the webapp.

How do I create a virtual directory or similar in wso2? That directory can be general, i mean it is not needed to be related to the webapp examples: localhost:80/**myDirectory**/ and localhost:80/**myApplication**/**myDirectory**/ are valid approaches to me.

There are some clear instructions to do it in tomcat but I can't find out how to translate this to tomcat in wso2.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the sample available [here.](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/products/as/5.0.0/modules/samples/product/VirtualDirectoryListing)